# How to add wifi driver to buildroot

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'd like to add following wifi driver to Amlogic buildroot

`https://github.com/khadas/android_hardware_wifi_icomm_drivers_ssv6xxx/tree/khadas-vims-pie`

I've copied driver source code to

`hardware/aml-4.9/wifi/icomm/drivers` then created folder `buildroot/package/amlogic/icomm`.

Now I need to create Config.in and icomm_wifi.mk in `buildroot/package/amlogic/icomm`

But I have no clue.

Comment: Driver is a part of the kernel. The best way us to integrate driver into kernel sources.

Answer (score 0):

The driver has to be built separately from the kernel itself, as a separate package. The [Buildroot documentation](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_packages_building_kernel_modules) explains how to do that.